# Sorting Prompts Alphabetically

Tags: javascript, prompt, alphabetical

Looking how to write a program where the user **enters** two **names** which will then return an **alert message** with the names listed in **alphabetical** order.

```
<script>
  let nameOne = prompt('Enter a name');
  let nameTwo = prompt('Enter another name');

  function aOrder() {
    if (nameOne !== nameTwo) {
      nameOne.split(',');
      nameTwo.split(',');
      let names = nameOne + nameTwo;
      names.sort(); 
      alert(names.join('nameOne,nameTwo')); 
    }else if (nameOne == nameTwo) {
      alert('The names are identical'); 
    }
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could add the two names to an array and sort it using the sort function.

```js
var name1 = 'somename';
var name2 = 'anothername';

console.log([name1,name2].sort().join(', '));
```